# How to create costume tag using react jsx

Tags: reactjs, components, jsx

```
<If condition={true}><div> Display when condition is true</div></If>
<If condition={false}><div> Doesn't Display when condition is false</div></If>
```

How to create customized  tag in react and use it with out importing.

Answer (score 0):

To do it, you have to write something like that:

```
{ 
  condition
  ? <div> Display when condition is true</div>               // if true
  : <div> Doesn't Display when condition is false</div>      // if false
}
```

You can also use `&&` if you want to display something only if condition is true (if false, dont display anything.

```
{
   condition &&  <div> Display when condition is true</div> 
}
```

Comment: but i don't want to use ternary operator under return. Is it possible to create custom tag like <If> with condition using jsx ?

Comment: If you will create an component like <If > then you can enter it in props, but why you wanna make your work harder?